# Calculation of average NDVI of area in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, ndvi, vegetation-index

I wish to calculate the average NDVI value of an area (polygon). Thus the average value of all pixel.

How can this be done in QGIS?

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I will do so in future.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS has a plugin called zonal statistics that will allow you to calculate the mean NDVI. It will also calculate the pixel count, and the sum of all pixel values within each polygon.

If you wish to sample multiple rasters, I'd recommend using the Zonal Stats module in [RSGISLib](http://www.rsgislib.org/rsgislib_zonalstats.html). This will allow you to iterate over multiple rasters using the same shapefile, exporting the data as a CSV or an ESRI shapefile.